# Extending animation out-of-range by looping, repeat, or cycle

Tags: animation

I'm trying to look for an easy way to extend a simulation in one of several modes, similar to that in [3ds Max "out-of-range" feature](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/3DSMax-Animation/files/GUID-8D3FF404-082E-44D5-99B1-68F960A45D0D-htm.html), where I can specify that the simulation should repeat or be extended before and after the first and last keyed frames.

The feature dialog in 3ds Max shows a dialog that allows you to select what might happen before and after what is keyed, such as Constant (nothing, disabled), Cycle (repeat the animation), Loop, Ping Pong, Linear, Relative repeat (repeat from the present position, rotation):

[image]

How can I accomplish this in blender?

Comment: Use extrapolation in the graph editor. Then you can use modifiers to set ranges or combine motions. In the key menu you can mirror and there are other choices in the interpolation controls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible by using *Keyframe Extrapolation*, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> in the Graph Editor. This shortcut is also available in the Timeline and Dope Sheet, and you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to quickly access the Graph Editor from any of those panels.

[image]

Further, you can change *Keyframe Interpolation* with <kbd>T</kbd>

[image]

Finally, you can fine-tune these *Modifiers* in the Graph Editor under the <kbd>N</kbd> menu to restrict their frame range, among other adjustments.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible somehow to use this with cloth animation?   For example I have an short animation of a flag waving in Wind & gravity.   The references I've seen using messy MDD exp/imp doesn't seem to work, and using mathematically combined multiple Sine waves is a disappointment compared to a loping flapping flag.  This is where editing an endpoint of a cycle and then cycling the animation is a superior solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, these methods only cover f-curves/keyframes indeed, not simulations. Some simulations can be semi-looped by setting the start frame to a precise negative point, or by manipulating the cache. From what I see, MDD really is the way to go for looping a cloth sim, perhaps it's worth another shot.